# Sumif formula with 2 "not" criteria in the same column

Tags: excel, formula, sumifs

I need to exclude two specific strings from a sumifs formula, but when I use the brackets, it only excludes the first value. Any idea why this is?

`=SUMIFS([Sum Range], [Column 1], "[Criteria 1]", [Column 2], {"<>[Criteria 2.1]","<>[Criteria 2.2]"})`

Is there any way I can solve this without having to rewrite the SUMIFS to subtract out Criteria 2.2?

Thank you!

Comment: You have an answer below but the reason your current formula with an array of constant strings in a **not** operation is not working correctly is that when even when a row in column 2 is **not** Criteria 2.1, it could be Criteria 2.2.

Comment: Thank you, @Jeeped. Do you know why the formula works this way and does not work if you wanted to include only 2.1 and 2.2 in the way Kyle mentioned below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
=SUMIFS([Sum Range], [Column 1], "[Criteria 1]", [Column 2], "<>[Criteria 2.1]",[Column 2],"<>[Criteria 2.2]")
```